# Linking SFST with python?

Tags: python, nlp, transducer, fst

I've used SFST language for my project on Natural Language Processing. 
How do I link or import SFST to my python code?

some link I referred:

http://home.gna.org/pysfst/tests/intro.html
ftp://ftp.ims.uni-stuttgart.de/pub/corpora/SFST/SFST-Manual.pdf

commands from the first link isn't working and sfst is not being setup.

Comment: What does `import sfst` return in python?  I notice that `sfst` is not in pip, so I am not sure how you install it if it isn't already there.  The links you posted don't say much about module installation.  I noticed there is an ubuntu package `sfst` installable via `apt-get` but no `pysfst`. After hunting around a bit, I found this document: http://www.cis.uni-muenchen.de/~schmid/tools/SFST/

Comment: http://home.gna.org/pysfst/tests/intro.html

Comment: http://home.gna.org/pysfst/tests/intro.html           this link says to type "import sfst" to link SFST to python . tried this but sfst is not being imported So we downloaded pysfst from "   Download URL: http://download.gna.org/pysfst/pysfst-1.1.3.tar.bz2  " and tried installing it with  command " python setup.py install" which again didn't work giving an error :                                 pysfst-1.1.3/SFST/src/fst-compiler-include.C: No such file or directory
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
error: command 'g++' failed with exit status 4
what do we do from here?

Answer (score 1):

(I can't comment, so I'll write my comment here:)

It seems that pysfst is currently outdated (anyone please correct me if I'm wrong). I also couldn't install pysfst via pip. Like @jeevan, I also tried to build pysfst from the sources (http://download.gna.org/pysfst/pysfst-1.1.3.tar.bz2), but failed.

I think the problem is that according to http://gna.org/projects/pysfst, pysfst supports SFST version 1.1. The latest SFST version at this time is 1.4.7a. The Ubuntu packages `sfst` and `libsfst1-4` support SFST version 1.4.6g. Compiling pysfst requires SFST 1.1 sources, which are currently not available from the SFST home page (http://www.cis.uni-muenchen.de/~schmid/tools/SFST/).